# Cross compile to esp-idf

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, esp32, esp-idf

I would like to use this library in ESP32:
https://github.com/CoolProp/CoolProp.git

It needs to be cross compiled.

And I have searched half the internet but no luck.

Anyone? Somewhere?

Comment: It only needs to be cross-compiled if esp-idf doesn't have a native compiler.

Comment: That's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

This library is for Mac, Windows or Linux. If you wish to port it to ESP32, it'll be a challenge - to put it mildly. There are no instructions for such work. You need to know (or learn) the code, the tools, the platform and figure it out.

Comment: It seems to be so, after few days of searching. I thought that I am not the only one with this problem and there would be tools to do this with a press of a button.